# running container from private registry with docker swarm

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run an image from a private registry with docker swarm.

I have an image I've tagged and pushed to a private registry. If I run this locally:

`docker run -p 8000:8000 -d registry.mydomain.com:8080/myimage`

it runs fine.

If I activate my swarm and try and run from there:

`$(docker-machine env --swarm swarm-master)
docker login registry.mydomain.com:8080
docker run -p 8000:8000 -d registry.mydomain.com:8080/myimage`

I get "Authentication is required".

I'm actually trying to do this via the docker remote API, but first I figure I should get it running on the command line.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/374

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, you are using authentication, but no SSL? I think docker only supports basic authentication over SSL. You could try to start docker with the insecure flag to at least try out the capabilities of swarm.

```
docker -d --insecure-registry registry.mydomain.com:8080
```

The error you are getting is probably docker swarm host trying to pull down the image from your registry first since run can be short hand for pull me this image and run it.

Comment: Uh, what's the command to use with Docker? Docker requires a command first. `unknown docker COMMAND: 'd' in -d`